# Is there some way I can make blend reload a project which has been modified in Visual Studio?

Tags: expression-blend, blend

I have a Visual Studio solution which is open in both blend 2 SP1 and VS2008 SP1 simultaneously.

If I make changes in VS, then switch over to blend, it notices that the project has changed and reloads things, however this is really unreliable. Sometimes it doesn't notice changes, and sometimes it does notice changes, but doesn't reload all the files that were changed. Notably the following:

1. If I have a xaml file open in blend, and edit it in VS, when I switch back to blend, often it does not pick up the edited source code
2. If I add a new file to the project using VS (an image or xaml file or anything), and switch back to blend, it does not show the added file.

The only way I've been able to get blend to notice these changes is to close the project and re-open, or to quit and re-start blend. This is *really* annoying. What I'd like to do is force blend to reload the project without having to close and re-open it.

This seems like something which should be obvious and easy (F5 would be nice), but I've not been able to find anything! Help!

Comment: It "notices" only if you save the file you are working on first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After watching a TechEd video of Jonas Follesoe doing some silverlight dev in blend, I noticed he kept repeatedly doing a "Rebuild Solution" from inside blend.

I tried doing this, and it seems to have made the problem go away. I'm not entirely sure if it's fixed, but it does seem to be a bit better now.